# Prototype to dynamically load a file?

Tags: prototypejs

As with jQuery, you can use .load to dynamically load a file.

I'm using using a pretty large script that uses Prototype JS framework, so I can't implement jQuery because they conflict. (I know of the noConflict workaround however this script is so big I can't implement that into every file).

Does Prototype have a similar function to dynamically load another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [XHR](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) which in Prototype is conveniently presented as [`Ajax.Updater`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/).